# Timestamp wrong time

Tags: php, timestamp

This is my problem

My default timezone is `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid')`

```
actual time 2012-12-06 17:00:38
start time 2012-12-10 16:30:00

unix timestamp actual time 1354809638
unix timestamp start time 1350052200
```

Start time is greater then actual time. But "unix timestamp actual time" is greater then "unix timestamp start time".

I wonder why?

RELEVANT CODE:

```
$to_unix_startTime = new DateTime($postField['startTime']);
$UnixStartTime = $to_unix_startTime->format('U');
```

$date = new DateTime(); 
$actualTime = $date->getTimestamp();

```
$start = new DateTime($postFields['startAuct']);
        $start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').PHP_EOL;
        $start_tmstmp = date_timestamp_get($start);
        $date = new DateTime(); 
        $timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
        if ($timestamp > $start_tmstmp) {
            echo $auctStatus = 1;
        } elseif ($timestamp < $start) {
            echo $auctStatus = 4;
        }
```

Comment: how are you getting timestamp ?

Comment: $date = new DateTime();
$timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();

Comment: Can you provide us the full relevant code of how you are setting up both dates and print the formatted dates and the timestamps? (Including any code where you possibly alter timezone settings in between). Please do so, by editing you question, not by pasting it in a comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$postField['startTime']` is in the wrong format. How do I know this? The timestamp you got from the start date, `1350052200`, represents date `2012-10-12` (October 12th 2012) in stead of `2012-12-10` (December 10th 2012).

`$postField['startTime']` is probably in the format `10/12/2012` (which will be parsed by `DateTime` as an American style date), when it should be formatted as `10-12-2012` (which will be parsed by `DateTime` as a European style date).

So, concluding, check the format of `$postField['startTime']` and make sure it is a European style representation of a date.

**[edit]** Compare:

```
$european = new DateTime( '10-12-2012' );
$american = new DateTime( '10/12/2012' );

echo $european->format( 'Y-m-d' ) . ' (' . $european->getTimestamp() . ')' . PHP_EOL;
echo $american->format( 'Y-m-d' ) . ' (' . $american->getTimestamp() . ')' . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Ok. This could help. I will try.

Comment: I just tested it and got exactly the same result! Good job, @fireeyedboy!

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved. You're right the format of my date was 10/12/2012 y changed to 10-12-2012. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to format the datetime before getting the timestamp.

Check my code here: https://compilr.com/shadyyx/datetime/index.php

Should there be any problem with the link, here is the code without output:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');

$start = new DateTime('2012-12-10 16:30:00');
$actual = new DateTime('2012-12-06 17:00:38');

echo $start->format('d.m.Y H:i:s').PHP_EOL;
echo $actual->format('d.m.Y H:i:s').PHP_EOL;
echo PHP_EOL;

$start_tmstmp = $start->getTimestamp();
$act_tmstmp = $actual->getTimestamp();

echo $start_tmstmp.PHP_EOL;
echo $act_tmstmp.PHP_EOL;
echo PHP_EOL;

var_dump($start_tmstmp > $act_tmstmp);
```

Comment: Better coding but I have the same problem.